# Код ИЗ Svn в Git

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

в svn  есть строка

```
svn export --force $SVN_PATH ./yourproject-tmp > /dev/null
```

получается он экспортирует все файлы проекта из svn_path  в созданную папку yourproject-tmp, которая находится в /dev/null ? Верно?

как сделать такое на git ? archive сразу архивирует? может его ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> которая находится в /dev/null

Нет. `> /dev/null` - это перенаправление вывода в никуда. Таким способом подавляют вывод сообщений на экран.

В гите примерный аналог экспорта - клонирование.

```
git clone $GIT_PATH
```